# Wallet Extension - "From apps on your iPhone" option in Apple Wallet App not showing

Tags: swift, applepay, ios-app-extension, apple-wallet, walletextension

I'm implementing Wallet Extension for adding credit card on wallet, I created both extension, UI and NonUI, but the "From apps on your iPhone" option never shows to me.

My extensions have the same entitlements of main app, with the com.apple.developer.payment-pass-provisioning.

**My NonUI status function implementation:**

```
final class MBFApplePayNonUIExtensionHandler: PKIssuerProvisioningExtensionHandler { 

    override func status(completion: @escaping (PKIssuerProvisioningExtensionStatus) -> Void) { 
        let status = PKIssuerProvisioningExtensionStatus() 
        status.requiresAuthentication = true 
        status.passEntriesAvailable = true 
        status.remotePassEntriesAvailable = true
        completion(status) 
    } ....
```

**I tried this to: **

```
final class MBFApplePayNonUIExtensionHandler: PKIssuerProvisioningExtensionHandler { 

    override func status(completion: @escaping (PKIssuerProvisioningExtensionStatus) -> Void) {
        let status = PKIssuerProvisioningExtensionStatus() 
        status.requiresAuthentication = true completion(status) 
    } ....
```

**Extensions .plists:**

**NonUI:**

```
 <plist version="1.0"> 
<dict> 
<key>NSExtension</key> 
<dict>
 <key>NSExtensionPointIdentifier</key>
 <string>com.apple.PassKit.issuer-provisioning</string>
 <key>NSExtensionPrincipalClass</key>
 <string>MBFApplePayNonUIExtensionHandler</string> 
</dict> 
</dict>
</plist>
```

**UI:**

```
<plist version="1.0"> 
<dict> 
<key>NSExtension</key> 
<dict> 
<key>NSExtensionMainStoryboard</key>
 <string>MBFApplePayUIExtension</string>
 <key>NSExtensionPointIdentifier</key> 
<string>com.apple.PassKit.issuer-provisioning.authorization</string>
 </dict>
 </dict>
 </plist>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Did you finish the extensions correctly? I have the same problems

Comment: @IgorStrekha no, still stuck :(

Comment: I have implemented first Extension (xamarin.forms). But second (UI) did not invoke. If you want please type me skype: spikaa1

Comment: Check Your UI and NonUI info.plist file as below example (NSExtensionPrincipalClass) :-

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
 <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
 <dict/>
 <key>NSExtension</key>
 <dict>
  <key>NSExtensionPointIdentifier</key>
  <string>com.apple.PassKit.issuer-provisioning</string>
  <key>NSExtensionPrincipalClass</key>
<string>$(PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME).IssuerExtensionHandler</string>
 </dict>
</dict>
</plist>

Comment: After 1 month I implemented full Wallet Extensions (UI + NONUI) by xamarin.forms

Comment: Having same issue. @IgorStrekha can you please share details to fix this issue.

Comment: do you have `com.apple.developer.payment-pass-provisioning` entitlement for the extensions?